# What is the correct behavior of a C/C++ program switch statement when it goes to a undefined case and lacks a default:?

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

My question concerns how compilers are permitted to implement switch statements in C and C++.

If the `case` is missing for the variable but no `default` is provided with the program attempt to "jump" to an odd calculated offset or is this trapped in someway to prevent potential problems with control flow?

Comment: `C/C++` is UB, anyway.. :)

Comment: Then it won't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the `C11` standard, chapter §6.8.4.2, The `switch` statement(*emphasis mine*)

> [...] If a converted value matches that of the promoted controlling expression,
>   control jumps to the statement following the matched `case` label. Otherwise, if there is
>   a `default` label, control jumps to the labeled statement. **If no converted case constant
>   expression matches and there is no `default` label, no part of the switch body is
>   executed.**

So basically, control goes past the entire `switch` body.

For `C++`, the logic is same. From `C++11`, §6.4.2, <sup>[Thanks to @Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921814/what-is-the-correct-behavior-of-a-c-c-program-switch-statement-when-it-goes-to/36921864#comment61405294_36921864)</sup>

> If no `case` matches and if there is no `default` then none of the statements in the `switch` is executed.

Comment: As per C++11 standard, things goes the same way at §6.4.2: _If no case matches and if there is no default then none of the statements in the switch is executed._

Comment: @Jack Thanks, let me add that to my answer itself. :)